# Which button was clicked in Java?

Tags: java

I'm working (failing pretty bad so far tbh) on a battleship game for my high school Java programming class. So far I have the game board for both the computer and the player and I have generated the ships for the computer and made sure the player can sink them. Both of the boards have a grid layout, and each of them is assigned to a 2-D array for both the player and the computer and is part of the specific Grid Layout (to be honest I don't really understand a lot of the code because it was supplied by our teacher, so I can't really tell which parts are relevant and which aren't - which is also why I am not posting any of my code).

What I want to do now is let the Player place their ships by letting them pick a starting place by clicking on the board.

```
inside of a for loop
            1: a button in buttonsPlayer is clicked
            2: when a button is clicked, the two coordinates are calculated and stored as x, y coordinates 
            3: a ship is generated with the starting coordinates of x, y
```

I know how to generate a ship with random x and y starting coordinates as I have done that before. Is there a way to get a button's number in an array after clicking on a button?

(I did read through like 5 other threads on here that seemed to ask the same question, but I don't really get any of the answers)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that `extends JButton` and adds more functionality to a `JButton` like so:

```
public class BoardPiece extends JButton{
     private int x,y;
     //rest of class including getters and setters
}
```

This will bring all the functionality of `JButton` along with it and you can add in essentially *meta-data* about each square.

Then in your event listener you would be able to just call `.getX()` and `.getY()` like so:

```
boardPiece.addActionListener((e)->{
    BoardPiece clicked = (BoardPiece)e.getSource();
    int x = clicked.getX();
    // and so on

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A JButton has an 'action command' which allows you to put information in it to distinquish it from other buttons.

using

```
JButton.setActionCommand
JButton.getActionCommand
```

So if you encode the coordinates of that button in that string, in your actionListener you can

```
JButton b = (JButton) eventListener.getSource();
```

and

```
String cmd = b.getActionCommand();
```

and then process that cmd string to figure out where on the board you are.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a JButton an ActionCommand, e.g.

```
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    button1.setActionCommand("Button1id");`
```

Then if you implement an `ActionListener` to listen for the buttonpress, you can write code like

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String buttonid = ae.getActionCommand();
    }
```

By checking the value of `buttonid`, you will know which button was pressed.

Comment: What exactly does "Button1id" in the setActionCommand means? Is it just a name to identify the action, or does it need to be something specific?

Comment: It's just something to identify it.  It can be any String.  You could put some data in there, like a number which you could parse.